# Can't retrieve information out of a method in C#?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    public static void GetSchoolInfo()
    {
        string SchoolName,
               EnrollmentStatus,
               ColorOne,
               ColorTwo;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your school name: ");
        SchoolName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Enrollment Status: ");
        EnrollmentStatus = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Pleas enter one of your school's colors: ");
        ColorOne = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the other school color: ");
        ColorTwo = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetSchoolInfo();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

etc

My purpose is to create a method that gets these strings then outputs them all nicely.
I cannot seem to call the SchoolName string, or any of the other strings for that matter, outside of the method. I am currently in school for my Bach in C.S. so forgive me as this is a novice question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning void return a new instance of a class that you can use inside main:

```
        public class SchoolInfo
        {
            public string SchoolName { get; set; }
            public string EnrollmentStatus { get; set; }
            public string ColorOne { get; set; }
            public string ColorTwo { get; set; }
        }

        public static SchoolInfo GetSchoolInfo()
        {
            string SchoolName,
                   EnrollmentStatus,
                   ColorOne,
                   ColorTwo;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your school name: ");
            SchoolName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Enrollment Status: ");
            EnrollmentStatus = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Pleas enter one of your school's colors: ");
            ColorOne = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the other school color: ");
            ColorTwo = Console.ReadLine();

            return new SchoolInfo()
                {
                    SchoolName = SchoolName,
                    EnrollmentStatus = EnrollmentStatus,
                    ColorOne = ColorOne,
                    ColorTwo = ColorTwo
                };
        }


        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SchoolInfo info = GetSchoolInfo();
            Console.WriteLine("You Entered School Name: "+info.SchoolName);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of their scope. Scope is determined by where variables are defined, and they are defined in your example inside of a method. So that is where their scope lays. Methods go out of scope quickly, and as such, so do their local variables. If you want access outside of the class to those variables, you should define them as class variables like this:

```
class Program
{
    string SchoolName,
           EnrollmentStatus,
           ColorOne,
           ColorTwo;
public static void GetSchoolInfo()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your school name: ");
    SchoolName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Enrollment Status: ");
    EnrollmentStatus = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Pleas enter one of your school's colors: ");
    ColorOne = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the other school color: ");
    ColorTwo = Console.ReadLine();
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetSchoolInfo();

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi as @Adam Maras mentioned, you are trying to access a variable which is no longer in your scope. When you declare a variable within a function, it lives and dies within that function. That means you will no longer have access to it from outside of the function.

Now the solution; create a class to hold the variables and use to across your main application.

Following is a demo.

These are fundaments of programming and knowing the fundamentals will take you a long way.. good luck

```
public class SchoolInfo
{
    /* two properties are defined as public to carry the data */
    public string NameOfTheSchool { get; set; }
    public string AddressOfTheAchool { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    public static void GetSchoolInfo(SchoolInfo info)
    {
        info.NameOfTheSchool = "AA";
        info.AddressOfTheAchool = "BB";
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // create the instance of the class
        SchoolInfo mySchoolInfo = new SchoolInfo();

        // pass it into GetSchoolInfo to collect the data
        GetSchoolInfo(mySchoolInfo);

        // print the value of the name of the school
        Console.WriteLine(mySchoolInfo.NameOfTheSchool);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't access those variables outside the `GetSchoolInfo` method is that they are local variables, and are therefore out of [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) anywhere outside that method. I'd [read up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2007/11/09/local-variable-scoping-in-c.aspx) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The method is declared as a `void` function.  Because the variables `SchoolName`, `EnrollmentStatus`, `ColorOne`, and `ColorTwo` are local variables and are not returned, you cannot access them outside of the `GetSchoolInfo()` function.  You can either declare them as global variables or create a `Collection` and return them from the function.  I prefer option 2, but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables defined in your GetSchoolnfo() method are local to that method which means they are only accessible in that method. You can define them as class level variables instead of method so that other methods can also access them.

```
class Program
{
    private String SchoolName;
    private String EnrollmentStatus;
    private String ColorOne;
    private String ColorTwo;

    public static void GetSchoolInfo()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your school name: ");
        SchoolName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Enrollment Status: ");
        EnrollmentStatus = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Pleas enter one of your school's colors: ");
        ColorOne = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the other school color: ");
        ColorTwo = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetSchoolInfo();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```